# Central Limit Theorem, Does $X_n (\omega)$ Converge Almost Surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

I'm studying for a final exam I have tomorrow and have a question about the following problem.

> Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ and let $P([a, b]) = b-a$ for all $0\le a\le b\le 1$. Let $X(\omega) = 0 $ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ an let $X_n (\omega) = 2^n \mathbf I_{[0,\frac{1}{n})} $ for $ n\ge 1$  Analyze whether $X_n (\omega) $ converges almost surely or only in probability to $X(\omega)$.

I believe $\mathbf I $ is an indicator function here.

We didn't cover this topic in too much detail, and I haven't done many problems involving the central limit theorem. So, I'd like to discuss whether my result is correct, if my reasoning for my answer is correct, and/or why I am wrong.

My answer to this problem is the following.

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n (\omega) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n \mathbf I_{[0,\frac{1}{n})} (\omega) = \infty  $$

Therefore, $X_n (\omega)$ does not converge. But, $X(\omega)$ converges to $0 \ \ \forall \ \ \omega \in \Omega $. Hence, $X_n (\omega) $ only in probability to $X(\omega)$.

I'm not sure how to apply the indicator function here, so this might be a source of error if my answer is incorrect. Are there more details I neglected to mention, how would a proper solution to this problem be described?

Thank you.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n I_{[0,1/n)}(\omega) = 0,$ not $\infty.$ (But that doesn't necessarily mean it converges a.s.).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, why? I have a feeling it has to do with the indicator function, since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n = \infty$

Comment: It does have to do with the indicator function. For any $\omega\in (0,1],$ there will be an $n$ such that $1/n <\omega,$ so the indicator is zero for all $m\ge n.$

Comment: And actually scratch what I said about that not necessarily meaning it converges almost surely. (It doesn't necessarily mean it converges in $L^p$, but that's not what you're asked about.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  That makes sense, I think.  So because $ \Omega = [0,1]$, $\omega \in \Omega$, and the indicator function is $1$ for values of $n$ on $[0,1/n)$, $\mathbf I$ is zero for all $X_n (\omega)$. So, $X_n (\omega)$ converges almost surely to $0$. Yes?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The subtlety here that this question doesn't touch on is that $E(X^n)\to \infty.$

Comment: Your response clarified a lot, thank you. If you want the points, I'll give you the accepted solution and a +1 if you post an answer below.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen if the limit equality holds for all $\omega$, can you explain why you wrote  "But that doesn't necessarily mean it converges a.s."?

Comment: @user52227, he changed his mind. Later in the comments, he said to disregard that statement.

Comment: @user52227 yeah, that was just a mistake. Think I was confused with the situation where the $X_n$ are independent and $2^n$ with probability $1/n,$ and $0$ otherwise. (And this problem had the flavor of a counterexample that would converge one way and not the other.) In fact this is a good example to show the converse of Borel Cantelli requires independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\omega,$ we have $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} I_{[0,1/n)}(\omega)2^n =0$$ since eventually $1/n<\omega.$ Thus the sequence $X_n$ is almost surely eventually zero. Thus it also converges in probability to zero.

However, it doesn't converge in $L^1$ since $$ E(X_n) = \frac{2^n}{n} \to \infty.$$